# Refresh browser when changing phone orientation

Tags: mobile, mobile-website

I've got an issue with a new website we're working on. We're using responsive CSS with Media Queries. The issue we have is that when the orientation of the phone changes, the CSS doesn't change (sometimes) until the page has been refreshed.

Is there anyway to refresh the browser automatically when the phone orientation changes?

I've found a link to the Safari Web 'Orientation' section which may help (Handling Orientation Events)? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Solution 1**

```
window.onorientationchange = function()
{
   window.location.reload();
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
if (window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() { location.reload(); }, false);
}
```

Your site will reload when phone orientation on change.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 ways of working with device orientation that might be helpful:
 http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/dealing-with-device-orientation